# How to create a user in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the latest version of the driver and MongoDB database 2.6 and I used to create users using the following code:

```
        MongoUser _user1 = new MongoUser("username", "password", false);

        MongoDatabase.AddUser(_user1);
```

and now it is saying `MongoDatabase.AddUser()` is deprecated by showing the following information:

> ...is obsolete: Use the new user management command 'createUser' or
>   'updateUser'."

Where is this new user management command? How do I create a user using the new MongoDB C# driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a search for 'createUser' on the latest code on the GitHub repository:
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/search?q=createUser&ref=cmdform

At the time of writing, the only reference to 'createUser' [is here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/c32ab672d601c652caf831603adc91b358854b8b/MongoDB.Driver/MongoDatabase.cs#L262)

The method has been marked as obsolete however [in this commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/commit/5fbcc15dc2b51d4343eb4f2c2e9797f2706617cc)

However; on closer inspection of the code, I [see this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/5fbcc15dc2b51d4343eb4f2c2e9797f2706617cc/MongoDB.Driver/MongoDatabase.cs#L267-L269):

```
if (_server.RequestConnection.ServerInstance.Supports(FeatureId.UserManagementCommands))
    {
        AddUserWithUserManagementCommands(user);
    }
    else
    {
       AddUserWithInsert(user);
    }
```

So, it is calling the required method under the hood

Answer (score 5):

For those interested in creating a user with the C# v2.0.1 driver and MongoDB v3.0.6 use the following:

```
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var database = client.GetDatabase("database_to_create_user_in");
var user = new BsonDocument { { "createUser", "fred" }, { "pwd", "some_secure_password" }, { "roles", new BsonArray { new BsonDocument { { "role", "read" }, { "db", "database_to_create_user_in" } } } } };
await database.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(user);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using MongoDB 2.6.2 and latest C# driver 1.9.2.
This is how you can add new users with 'createUser':

```
public static void AddUser(string user, string password, string[] roles)
{
    var database = GetDatabase();
    var command = new CommandDocument { { "createUser", user}, { "pwd", password }, { "roles", new BsonArray(roles) } };
    var result = database.RunCommand(command);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I struggled with the roles. I wanted to add an admin (initial user) to the mongodb. My working solution looks like that.

```
private static bool CreateAdminUser(string databaseUser, string databasePassword)
{
    try
    {
        var databaseName = "admin";
        var user = new CommandDocument
        {
            { "createUser", databaseUser },
            { "pwd", databasePassword },
            {
                "roles", new BsonArray
                {
                    new BsonDocument { { "role", "readWriteAnyDatabase" }, { "db", databaseName } },
                    new BsonDocument { { "role", "userAdminAnyDatabase" }, { "db", databaseName } },
                    new BsonDocument { { "role", "dbAdminAnyDatabase" }, { "db", databaseName } }
                }
            }
        };
        new MongoClient().GetServer().GetDatabase(databaseName).RunCommand(user);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```