# .net core + MongoDB how to create database dynamically

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core project with MongoDB.

Before starting to work with this I need to create DB for this manually.

I mean I need to go mongo shell and use next commands like this:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "abc123!",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
);
exit;
```

But I don't like do this every time when I need to deploy my project.

How can I automate this process and creating DB dynamically from C# code or use some other solution if it's possible?

P.S. I use [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1151842/Using-MongoDB-NET-Driver-with-NET-Core-WebAPI) for building work with MongoDB + .net core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a mongoDb driver. U can get it via nuget.

In general u just instantiate a server object and call  GetDatabase to create a Database.

```
server.GetDatabase("myDB");
```

This way you can also create users using the mongoDb driver as mentioned here :
[How to create a user in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945020/how-to-create-a-user-in-mongodb)

Further reading:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.3.0

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/getting_started/installation/

The following Video provides a short tutorial how to do it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6x0-vHHHpv8
Thanks to that answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30629593/4992212